# Push to List Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My question is simple:

Can I do [something like this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#adding-new-items) in the current Firestore (as at 4.2.0)?
If so, please how?

```
const itemsRef = db.list('items');
itemsRef.push({ name: newName });
```

I just wanna push to an array, and can't seem to find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

[Sure you can](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection)!

> **Adding documents to a collection**
>   To add a new document to a collection with a generated id use the add() method. This method uses the type provided by the generic class to validate it's type structure.

So in your example this would be:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore): {
    const itemsCollections = db.collection('items');
    itemsCollections.add({ name: 'NewName' });
}
```